# Change text of a child element using native JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Using native JavaScript I need to change the text below that is `None` to `Black`

I know this would be easy with Jquery or other libraries but in this project I cannot use them, can someone help me to do this please?

```
<li>
  <input type="radio" id="options_82" class="radio product-custom-option" name="options[82]">
  <span class="label">
    <label for="options_82">None</label>
  </span>
</li>
```

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName('label')[0].innerHTML = "Black"; I hope it helps

Comment: Maybe [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_navigation.asp) could help you understand how to do it in "pure" JS instead of using JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the element using `querySelector`, `getElementById`, etc. and then set it to `'Black'` using either the `textContent` or `innerHTML` properties. It's best practice to use `textContent` unless you're actually setting HTML.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h4a9tg1b/)

```
document.querySelector('label[for="options_82"]').textContent = 'Black';
```

A more complex selector using the ID may be faster than the above:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mxmbf4bx/)

```
document.querySelector('#options_82 + .label label').textContent = 'Black';
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need to match for the `for` attribute (your html structure looks like you probably have more than one of these) you can use `getElementsByTagName` to fetch your labels, and then loop through them comparing the `for` attribute.

```
function getLabel(for) {
    var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
    for (var i = 0, c = labels.length; i < c; i++) {
        if (labels[i].getAttribute('for') === for) {
            return labels[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can edit the element's `innerHTML` value.

```
var label = getLabel('forvalue');
if (label) {
    label.innerHTML = 'new text';
}
```